# How to upgrade expo sdk to specific version

Tags: react-native, expo

I want to upgrade my expo sdk version step by step as recommended in the documentation. These are the instructions:

1. Update to the latest version of Expo CLI: npm i -g expo-cli. expo-cli@4.12.8 or greater is required.
2. Update to the latest version of EAS CLI if you use it: npm i -g eas-cli.
3. Run **expo upgrade** in your project directory.

I want to go **from version 42 to version 43 and not to the last version 44**. Is this possible?

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: When you run expo upgrade on terminal, you will be prompted with "You are currently using SDK 42.0.0. Would you like to update to the latest version, 47.0.0?" If you select No, the various versions to select from are presented which you can then choose from your preferred version.

Answer (score 23):

Try this

```
expo upgrade 43
```

This should solve your problem!

Answer (score 19):

Try this command :

```
  npm install expo@48 -g
```

Or :

```
  expo update 48
```

**NOTE:** version 48 released March 2, 2023

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. Didn't work for me but I have tried with yarn add expo@43. In package json expo version is now 43 but react-native is  "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-42.0.0.tar.gz". I suppose that I will have to continue working on that. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 5):

Here is how you can upgrade Expo SDK to the latest and specific version you want.

If you want to install the latest version

```
// Using NPM 
npm install expo@latest

// Using Yarn 
yarn add expo@latest
```

If you want to install the specific version here are the commands

```
// Using NPM (for example, 49 SDK version) 
npm install expo@49

// Using Yarn 
yarn add expo@49
```

Want to upgrade installed dependencies to match the installed expo version?

```
npx expo install --fix
```

If you’re using the Expo CLI, you can also use the `expo upgrade` command with the version number.

```
// For the latest version 
expo upgrade latest

// For Specific Version 
expo upgrade 49
```

---

[Upgrade Expo SDK doc](https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/upgrading-expo-sdk-walkthrough/)

Answer (score 3):

Just run

```
expo upgrade -h
```

You will see the options. You just have to specify the version, as other answers suggest:

```
expo upgrade 46
```

Answer (score 1):

Please upgrade the expo-cli version. I had the similar situation and the following command solved my problem.

```
expo-cli upgrade @43.0.0
```

Since in your scenario, you need to update to 43, the above command should work, else you can specify the version as you need.

Answer (score 0):

**Tested on 29th Sep, 2022**

Use `expo upgrade @43.0.0`

Answer (score 0):

upgrade package.json with all updated packages.
Remove node_module folder
run the cmd `npm install or yarn install`
also install `eas-build` for create new build.

Answer (score 0):

As everything seems not to work, please use this command `expo-cli upgrade`

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the official site and choose your sdk to upgrade to latest or mention to which sdk you want to upgrade.
Here is the offical link https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/upgrading-expo-sdk-walkthrough/

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `yarn add react-native@latest` OR `npm install react-native@latest`. This ensures you always have the most recent version of React Native. Ali Zaid's answers are also very useful for more specific use cases.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

> expo install expo-updates