# BREAKING CHANGE: The request './dist/abort-controller' failed to resolve only because it was resolved as fully specified

Tags: react-native, webpack, expo, expo-web, expo-core-modules

i've upgraded my expo version to sdk 48 and now my webpack is not working and its showing m

```
    Module not found: Can't resolve './dist/abort-controller'
Did you mean 'abort-controller.mjs'?
BREAKING CHANGE: The request './dist/abort-controller' failed to resolve only because it was resolved as fully specified
```

been doing some research and tried it but nothing works. please help

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you need to find that this is exactly coming from which library (eg. in my case it occurs with)

I have raised issue with expo on git - https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/22064

One workaround is
open file - `./node_modules/abort-controller/polyfill.mjs`
and change

```
import * as ac from "./dist/abort-controller"
```

to

```
import * as ac from "./dist/abort-controller.mjs"
```

(But changing in node_modiles is a bad idea)

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same issue. Did not find a solution but found a workaround:

1. You probably have made a commit before upgrading. revert to that commit. Otherwise revert to the last commit, that is functional
2. Delete `package-lock.json` and the `node_modules`
3. `npm install` to reinstall functional packages
4. See if it works `npm start`
5. [upgrade expo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72630357/how-to-upgrade-expo-sdk-to-specific-vresion) to a version that you think works

(I think this needs to be an issue, as it does not deliver appropriate info to resolve the issue with the package mentioned)